# how to convert html text in json to plain text in android

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-viewmodel

previously I tried integrating articles that I published on blogger to display it again in the android app that I developed, and at that time I got to know blogger api, one of the API providers to retrieve data posts from blogger to android using json and I implemented it with a view model to retrieve data from the blogger API, but a problem arises when I retrieve data content.

This is API link : https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3008269636405157859/posts?key=AIzaSyDDcYZkYnHtJTFm29xhZjlwCFsFh7meOQw (see json object : content)

and before that I have also implemented spanned json.object data retrieval in my code

itemmodel.java

```
public BlogItem(JSONObject jsonObject){
    try {
        String titleList = jsonObject.getString("title");
        String contentList = jsonObject.getString("content");
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(contentList);
        String formated = spanned.toString();

        this.titleBlog = titleList;
        this.contentBlog = formated;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

viewmodel.java (
to retrieve jsonobject data in the itemmodel.java class)

```
public void setBlog(final String blogs){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    final ArrayList<BlogItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/"+ID+"/posts?key="+API_KEY;

    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                String result = new String(responseBody);
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray list = responseObject.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0;i < list.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                    BlogItem blogItem = new BlogItem(jsonObject);
                    listItems.add(blogItem);
                }
                listBlog.postValue(listItems);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.d("onFailure", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

when I run the code above, the app cannot display the content that I took from the API and the app force closes,
but when I get spanned delete from itemmodel.class code, the content actually displays the same data in json content. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You may want to see if there is any crash message/info in thee logcat log